# SET DATEFIST = 1 not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm having trouble to make SET DATEFIRST to work properly on some simple queries I working on at the moment.

Here is my first example:

```
SET DATEFIRST = 1
SELECT count(Distinct ID)
FROM Products
WHERE
Location in (12) 
and YEAR (CREATED) = '2018'
Group by datepart(wk, created), year(created)
```

The above code gives me some results correct and some others wrong. It's basically counting from Monday to Monday, but I want it to count from Monday to Sunday. I still don't understand why it's counting 8 days instead of 7 days on some of the weeks.

Also I have multiple selections with SET DATEFIRST = 1 which also doesn't work:

```
SET DATEFIRST = 1
--Products finished this week  
SELECT count(Distinct ID)
FROM Products
WHERE
Created >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND Created <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
AND Location in (15,16,17) AND (Location IS NOT NULL OR Location NOT IN(18))
UNION ALL
--------------------------------------------
-- Products received this week
SELECT count(Distinct ID)
FROM Products
WHERE 
Created >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND Created <  DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()),getdate())))
AND Location in(1)
```

The above code is not reacting to SET DATEFIRST = 1
It's not counting from Monday to sunday, instead it's counting from Sunday to sunday (8 days)

Comment: It's unclear to me how you're determining anything of what it's doing when all that you're outputting is counts. What has led you to your current conclusions about how it's working? Some *sample data* and *expected results* may also improve this immensely.

Comment: Hello!
How I got to my conclusion is by actually doing the count in sql between 2 dates where the numbers didn't match. When I did count from Monday to Sunday I also counted the Sunday from the previous week and the numbers matched all the sudden.

Comment: Just curious why you are converting GETDATE() to a DATE in order to use it in DATEADD. I don't think that conversion is needed.

Comment: @MishMish - but since your queries don't output any week numbers *at all*, how do you know which counts in your query correspond to any particular week?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue:

```
DATEADD(day, 8-datepart(DW, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())))
```

You are comparing a `DATETIME` from the database with a `TIME` to a `DATE` with no `TIME`. So the `DATE` portions on next Monday will be equal and your < will fail.

This will not work because the DB field is a `DATETIME` and you are comparing to a `DATE`.

```
SET @D= '06/25/2018 01:20:23 AM' --Monday next week with a time
IF(@D < DATEADD(day, 8-datepart(DW, GETDATE()), CONVERT(GETDATE()))) --<--The whole day 
    SELECT 1 -- '06/25/2018 12:00:23 AM' < (DATE)2018-06-25    
ELSE  
    SELECT 2
```

Returns 2

If you do want to include everything through Sunday then you need to set the cutoff to 12:00:00 AM Monday morning. One way to do that would be something like:

```
DATEADD(DAY,0,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()),getdate())))
```

Comment: Hi
I edited my answer with your suggestion. But it's still counting from Sunday (previous week) until Sunday (the week after)

Comment: I bet you need to do that to both ends of the date comparison. You can also use @Date BETWEEN LowDate AND HighDate construct here.